# Printing a variable post-operation in Python

Tags: python, variables, printing

In Perl, the following code:

```perl
for(my $j = $mss; $j > 5; $j--) {
   print Vfile "    s$j <= s", $j-1, ";\n"
}
```

yields the following in a text file:

```
s7 <= s6;
s6 <= s5;
```

I am trying to have the same thing appear in Python with the following code:

```py
for j in range(mss, 5, -1):
   f.write("s%(j)d <= s(%(j)d-1);\n" % locals())
```

But I get unsolved arithmetic operation as follows:

```
s7 <= s(7-1);
s6 <= s(6-1);
```

How can I have the arithmetic operations resolved in Python like you see in Perl?

Comment: Use an f-string: `f.write(f's{j} <= s{j-1};')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: How to do math using f-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49344643/python-how-to-do-math-using-f-string)

Comment: Do it the same as in Perl, by giving `j-1` as a separate argument to `print()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression `"s%(j)d <= s(%(j)d-1);\n" % locals()` can perhaps be written more clearly as:

```
"s%d <= s(%d-1);\n" % (j, j)
```

This will replace the `%d` placeholders, but the `-1` is not part of the format placeholder. Instead, as in Perl, we'd have to do the calculation *before* replacing the placeholders:

```
"s%d <= s%d;\n" % (j, j - 1)
```

Nowadays, Pythons `%`-formatting is rarely used since `f""`-strings allow us to express this more directly:

```
f"s{j} <= s{j - 1};\n"
```

Comment: Thank you. Our Linux systems' python version doesn't support f-string yet so I have to do this cumbersome method.

Comment: @RenovatioTommy oof, f-strings were introduced in Python 3.6, which is five years old and already end-of-life. But there's nothing wrong with using Python's other formatting methods, in particular percent-formatting (as shown in this answer), or str.format (`"s{} <= s{};\n".format(j, j -1)`), or (sometimes) using string concatenation (`"s" + str(j) + " <= s" + str(j - 1) + ";\n"`)